# Using selenium: How to keep logged in after closing Driver in Python

Tags: python, selenium, automation, web-crawler, bots

I want to get my Whatsapp web (web.whatsapp.com) logged in, at the second time opening the Whatsapp web on chrome driver. Following is my code based on Python need your help.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options


chrome_path = r"chromedriver.exe"
options = Options();
options.add_argument("user-data-
dir=C:/Users/Username/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/User Data");
#options.add_argument("--start-maximized");
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_path,chrome_options=options);

#driver = webdriver.Chrome();
driver.get('https://web.whatsapp.com/')
```

Comment: Where are you stuck exactly? What is the error? On which line? Can you update the error stack trace in the Question area?

Comment: Actually the problem in this code is that, each time this code needs login. And I want to get rid from login each time.

Comment: For that you need to store and save the cookies.

Comment: Can you guide me ? How can I do that with current version of the code.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I tried on my Mac, below code and it worked perfectly fine, I don't need to login again

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options


options = Options()
options.add_argument("user-data-dir=/tmp/tarun")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)

driver.get('https://web.whatsapp.com/')
driver.quit()
```

For window you can try changing the path as below

```
options.add_argument("user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\Username\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data")
```

Comment: @DaniyalTariq, Did you mean not working? now working?

Comment: thanks for the help. I changed the path on windows it is working now.

Comment: Do you know how many minutes it will stay connected ?

Answer (score 1):

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options


options = Options()
options.add_argument("user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\Username\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)

driver.get('https://web.whatsapp.com/')
driver.quit()
```

Here it is for Windows. Works perfect on Python 3.6